# Spring Data Mongo: IllegalArgumentException trying to use field reference for minus()

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to use the `$subtract` operator to project the difference between two fields as a separate third field using this line of code:

```
pipeline.add(Aggregation.project("createdTime","modResult").andExpression("createdTime").minus("modResult").as("bucketedTime"));
```

However, when I try to perform the aggregation, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Fields$AggregationField
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I've noticed that if I provide an integer instead of a field name, there is no issue.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my question [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1310), it turns out I should have been using `and()` instead of `andExpression()`.  The latter tries to interpret the argument as an expression, such as `field1 + field2` as a more convenient way of doing `.and("field1").plus("field2")`.